# Can I disable map panning when select annotations

Tags: ios, skmaps

I just started using SKMap library on IOS recently.

One behavior of the function `didSelectAnnotation` (from the `SKMapViewDelegate` Protocol), is that whenever an annotation got selected, the center of the map's visible region will move to the location of that annotation.

Is there any way that I can disable this?

Comment: you could remember your current view, save it and go back to it after the calloutview opened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually not a feature of `didSelectAnnotation`function, but rather of `showCalloutForAnnotation` function. Just set parameter `animated` in the function to NO.

Comment: The showCalloutForAnnotation:withOffset:animated: method centers the map on the annotation. If the user taps on an annotation, the map will not be centered on the selected annotation.